# NoSuchBeanDefinition due to unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jax-rs

I use a library X's class marked as a @Provider (annotation for JAX-RS).

I want to extend X's capabilities so I extend the class:

```
@Provider
public class WrappedX extends ContainerRequestFilter,
ContainerResponseFilter {
     private final X objectX;
     public WrappedX (X objectX) { this.objectX = objectX; } }
     @Override
     <Some function1>
     @Override
     <Some function2>
}
```

In another file I create the WrappedX Spring Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WrappedXConfig {
  @Bean
  public WrappedX getWrappedXFilter(){
      X objectX = new XBuilder().build();
      return new WrappedX(objectX);
  }

}
```

when I run this I get the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'getWrappedXFilter' defined in file 
    [<path>/WrappedX.class]: 

 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type  [org.company.package1.X]: : No qualifying bean of 
 type [org.company.package1.X] found for dependency: 
     expected at least 1 bean which qualifies 
     as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
  Dependency annotations: {};  nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
    No qualifying bean of type [org.company.package1.X] found 
    for dependency: expected at least 1 bean 
    which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
  Dependency annotations: {}
```

I see another piece of code that does exactly what I have done. But they run their code just fine. Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Can you please post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Can you please post your configuration regarding classpath scanning? My best guess is that the bean you're attempting to inject is not picked up by spring.

Comment: @ComponentScan(basePackages  = "org.company.package1")

Comment: How was this class org.company.package1.X made a bean ? Could you please share the class X ?

Comment: It was not made a bean. Class X is just a javax-rs @Provider class.

Comment: Sometimes _over_ generalizing code for a post, takes away some important context. I wonder if this may be one of those cases. Maybe it would be better to post some real code with real complete stacktrace and error message. Along with your Jersey configuration class and any other application configuration code.

Comment: Can't really post the exact example.